# Adding secondary axis in the many graphs

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot, seaborn

I am trying to add a secondary axis to the following codes for graphs. I want to add a secondary axes with another metric

```
plt.style.use('dark_background')
fig, (ax1,ax2,ax3,ax4) = plt.subplots(nrows=4, ncols=1,figsize=(18,12))

funnel.plot(x='date_event_nk', y='Show_Complete', label='Traditional', 
ax=ax1)
ax1.set_title("TRADITIONAL FUNNEL AND YOLO CONVERSION PWA")
ax1.xaxis.set_label_coords(1.05, -0.025)

funnel_yolo.plot(x='date_event_nk', y='Show_Complete', label='Yolo', ax=ax2)
ax2.set_title("TRADITIONAL FUNNEL AND YOLO CONVERSION PWA")
ax2.xaxis.set_label_coords(1.05, -0.025)

funnel_smartlock.plot(x='date_event_nk', y='SMRequest_Complete', 
label='Smartlock Auto', ax=ax3)
ax3.set_title('SMARTLOCK AUTO CONVERSION PWA')
ax3.set_ylim((0, 0.005))
ax3.xaxis.set_label_coords(1.05, -0.025)

funnel_smartlock_s.plot(x='date_event_nk', y='SMRequest_Complete', 
label='Smartlock Select', ax=ax4)
ax4.set_title('SMARTLOCK SELECT CONVERSION PWA')
ax4.set_ylim((0, 0.1))
ax4.xaxis.set_label_coords(1.05, -0.025)
```

My graphs are:

[image]

So as to add a new secondary axes in all the graphs i am trying the following 
(i just create in the first graph for simplicity, my problem is illustrate in my first graph)

```
plt.style.use('dark_background')
fig, (ax1,ax2,ax3,ax4) = plt.subplots(nrows=4, ncols=1,figsize=(18,12))

funnel.plot(x='date_event_nk', y='Show_Complete', label='Traditional', 
ax=ax1)
ax1.set_title("TRADITIONAL FUNNEL AND YOLO CONVERSION PWA")
ax1.xaxis.set_label_coords(1.05, -0.025)
ax5 = ax1.twinx()
ax5.plot(kind='bar',x='date_event_nk',y='One_tap_login',ax=ax5)

funnel_yolo.plot(x='date_event_nk', y='Show_Complete', label='Yolo', ax=ax2)
ax2.set_title("TRADITIONAL FUNNEL AND YOLO CONVERSION PWA")
ax2.xaxis.set_label_coords(1.05, -0.025)

funnel_smartlock.plot(x='date_event_nk', y='SMRequest_Complete', 
label='Smartlock Auto', ax=ax3)
ax3.set_title('SMARTLOCK AUTO CONVERSION PWA')
ax3.set_ylim((0, 0.005))
ax3.xaxis.set_label_coords(1.05, -0.025)

funnel_smartlock_s.plot(x='date_event_nk', y='SMRequest_Complete', 
label='Smartlock Select', ax=ax4)
ax4.set_title('SMARTLOCK SELECT CONVERSION PWA')
ax4.set_ylim((0, 0.1))
ax4.xaxis.set_label_coords(1.05, -0.025)
```

but is not working correctly

Comment: Are you trying to add a second x axis?  Have you looked through [The Gallery](https://matplotlib.org/gallery/index.html) to see if there was something similar to what you need/want?

Comment: What is not working correctly? What problem are you encountering? What is the problem in the figure you have posted above?

Comment: having this following error "inner() got multiple values for argument 'ax'"

Comment: Which line is throwing the error? It looks like it's coming from `ax5.plot(kind='bar',x='date_event_nk',y='One_tap_login',ax=ax5)`. Is it? It looks to me that you should write `ax5.plot(kind='bar',x='date_event_nk',y='One_tap_login')`

Comment: I think instead of `ax5.plot(..., ax=ax5)` you want to write `funnel.plot(..., ax=ax5)`.